# Use driver to deliver output depending on the state of an objects rotation

Tags: drivers

Im trying to solve a certain problem. i've tried several different approaches, but since i have not found any solution yet, i'm asking you guys.

I have a rotating object(1). Now i want an other object(2) to change the value of it's shape-keys, for only the duration of one quarter of object 1's full 360° turn. (=90°)

[image]

I don't want to keyframe the whole process because i have several rotating object, but they all rotate in different speeds and offsets. I want to be able to change the speed in which object 1 is turning without having to manually adjust object 2.
So i would like to use drivers for this task. But i have no idea of scripted expressions being any more complicated than e.g. var*.5 etc.
Can somebody show me a way (scripted expression) which delivers an output of 1 for the duration of a 90° rotation and 0 for the remaining 270°?
Or even an other approach.

Answer (score 2):

Angles 0-90° has positive cos and sin so we use this logic statements 
 `cos(rot)>0 and sin(rot) >0` which evaluate to 1 when the angle is 0-90° and 0 otherwise :

[image]

***Note:*** the angle is in radian

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Works perfectly fine!

Comment: @Järv you're welcome , drivers can handle much complex functions if you need so just ask

Comment: I've started to try around with some functions. But still I lack of the knowledge which terms are accepted.

Comment: E.g. I tried to offset the function above by 180°. Now the expression should evaluate to 1 when sin(rot) and cos(rot) both equal 0. ( means Object is rotating from 270° to 360°)
I hoped for a lucky shot by adding following expression: 
sin(rot) is 0 and cos(rot) is 0
but of course it didn't work. Any tips?

Comment: it will be `cos(rot) >0 and sin(rot)<0` in that quarter the cos is positive but the sin is negative